# Rails CDN URL not used in SASS Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, asset-pipeline

How can I ensure that the SASS helpers in the `sass-rails` gem generate URLs against my CDN?

I have this in my `application.rb`:

```
config.asset_host = 'https://cdn.host.com/'
```

Which makes it so the head of the document has:

```
<link href="https://cdn.host.com/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<link href="https://cdn.host.com/assets/application.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

However my CSS files look like this:

```
.splash { background: url('/assets/hero.png'); }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the **image_url** helper method in your SCSS file?

```
.splash { background: image_url('assets/hero.png'); }
```

[This article](http://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_deliver_your_static_images_through_a_cdn_in_ruby_on_rails) may help you out a bit, and fwiw, if you are using SASS (as opposed to SCSS) then you might need to use image-url instead of image_url, I don't know for sure though

**Update:**

```
.splash { background: image_url('/assets/hero.png'); }  // will still fetch from the localhost...
 .splash { background: image_url('assets/hero.png'); }  // work perfectly fine..
```

Comment: For me, switching from using image-url to using image_url did the trick. I could keep the slash.